# Media unavailable while sharing a file in android

Tags: android, file, apk, uri, share

I am implementing an android app that shares installed apps apk files.
All good; but while sharing, I received an error about "Media Unavailable."
How can I fix it?

Honestly, I am trying to share from SoutceDir and my app data folder (storage/emulated/ 0/Android/data/com.example.myAppName).

Please help me!

My code in the blow:

```
private void shareApk() {
    ArrayList<Uri> pickedAppsUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    // Preparing cache folder
    // Deleting older files
    for(File f : getExternalCacheDir().listFiles()){
        f.delete();
    }
    
    // Make a copy from selected apps apk files into cache folder
    for (int i = 0; i < apkPackageInfoList.size(); i++) {
        if (checkMarksVisibilityState.get(i)) {
            String apkFileName = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(apkPackageInfoList.get(i).applicationInfo) + "";
            File apkTmpFile = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), apkFileName+".apk");
            try {
                InputStream inStream = new  FileInputStream(new File(apkPackageInfoList.get(i).applicationInfo.sourceDir));
                OutputStream outTemp = new FileOutputStream(apkTmpFile);
                OutputStreamWriter writerTmp = new OutputStreamWriter(outTemp);
                writerTmp.write(inStream.read());
                outTemp.flush();
                outTemp.close();
                writerTmp.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {}
            pickedAppsUri.add(Uri.parse(apkTmpFile.getPath()));
        }
    }
    
    // Create share intent
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    if (pickedAppsUri.size() == 1) {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pickedAppsUri.get(0));
    } else {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pickedAppsUri);
    }
    for(ResolveInfo ri : getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,0)){
        for(Uri uri : pickedAppsUri){
            grantUriPermission(ri.activityInfo.packageName, uri, 1);
        }
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via:"));
}
```

[I think I do not access to sourceDir because the copied files in the Android/data/com.example.shareApk/cache folder is empty (0 bytes file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogqLP.jpg)

Comment: Please post the relevant code you use for sharing. Note that `InternalStorage/Android/data/com.example.myAppName` is not a valid Android path as `InternalStorage` is just the virtual root of the MTP file share.